# is there a simple way to use javascript replace to remove contents inside tags

Tags: javascript, regex

there is long string, like

```
<td>sdfaf</td><td width='1'></td><td width='1'>sdfdsf</td><td></td>
```

Is there a simple regex method to delete contents inside tags, convert it to

```
<td></td><td width='1'></td><td width='1'></td><td></td>
```

I know jquery html() and empty() can do the work, but I want to find a pure javascript method to do it.

thanks

Comment: I see you use the tag regex so I guess you thought it could be a good idea to try to use a regex to remove HTML content. I'll just let you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: thanks,  I just wonder is there a regex replace method can do same work like preg_replace function in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your "string" comes from a table in your document, here's how to do it in vanilla javascript :

```
var cells = yourtable.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (var i=0; i<cells.length; i++) cells[i].innerHTML = '';
```

(if you just have the string, you may simply create a `tr` node and set this string as innerHTML)

Answer (score 2):

try this simple code

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

for ( var counter = 0; counter < tds.length; counter++ )
{
  tds[ counter ].innerHTML = ""; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Rough and ready, assuming no angle brackets between or inside the tags:

```
 str = str.replace( />[^<]+<\//g, '></' );
```

Comment: @user995789. Why have you accepted an answer that doesn't "use javascript _replace_" and which is not a "simple _regex_ method"? Is it because of the high rep of the person that answered?